# Why vuex return object instead of array in Quasar App?

Tags: vuex, quasar

I have Quasar App
I connected vuex
I created a separate file as module for vuex like this:
I created an empty array in vuex
If I open Vue extension in browser I see that vuex return object where an array is stored instead of just an array

[image: Vuex]

**How can I store just an array instead of object?**

I created a vuex file like this:

[image: vuex fle]

in store/index.js file I imported cars.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import cars from "src/store/module-example/cars";

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default function (/* { ssrContext } */) {
  const Store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
     cars
    },

    // enable strict mode (adds overhead!)
    // for dev mode only
    strict: process.env.DEBUGGING
  })

  return Store
}
```

Cars.js file:

```
import axios from "axios";

const state = {
  cars: []
}

const mutations = {
  SET_CARS: (state, cars) => {
    state.cars = cars;
  }

}
const actions = {
  async GET_ALL_CARS_FROM_API({commit}) {
    let result = await axios.get('http://localhost:8050/api/cars');
    commit("SET_CARS", result.data)

  }
}

const getters = {
  GET_ALL_CARS: (state) => {
    return state.cars;
  }
}
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  mutations,
  actions,
  getters
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result.data` is an object. In order to set `cars` to a plain array just set it to `result.data.cars`

```
commit("SET_CARS", result.data.cars)
```